# Prove that $x-a \sin(x)=b$ has one real solution, where $0\lt a \lt 1 $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $x-a\sin(x)=b$ has one real solution, where $0\lt a \lt 1 $.

I need some sort of starting hint as to how to prove this.

I can define $g(x)= x-a\sin(x)-b$ but more than that I'm having difficulties proving. What theorem could I use?

Comment: You can use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that $g=0$ at at least one point, and then Rolle's Theorem or the Mean Value Theorem to show $g$ cannot equal zero at two points...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thank you! I knew I needed to use Rolle's theorem, just wasn't sure in conjunction with what!

Comment: It is easier than it looks. Just differentiate. If $0<a<1$ then $g'(x)>0$ for all $x$, so the $x-a\sin x$ is strictly monotonic. It clearly gets arbitrarily large (positive and negative), so there is just one solution for any given $b$.

Comment: You may not need to use Rolle's Theorem directly, only a standard consequence of the theorem. For $f'(x)=1-a\cos x\gt 0$, and therefore $f$ is everywhere increasing.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the function:
$$
f(x)=x-a\sin(x)-b
$$
This has derivative:
$$
f'(x)=1-a\cos(x)>0
$$
since $0<a<1$, so $f(x)$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence as $f(x)$ is continuous increasing and is negative for sufficiently negative $x$ and positive for sufficiently positive $x$ it has a zero on $\mathbb{R}$, and it is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Its derivative is always positive, strictly, since $$|asin(x)| \leq |a| <1.$$
So it has at most one zero.

When $x$ goes to infinities, we have positive and negative limits, meaning, by intermediate value theorem, that it does have one zero.